# .net MAUI templates not in Visual Studio 2022 community

Tags: maui

Can someone help me get the MAUI templates in Visual studio 2022 community? MAUI is installed.

It was working fine and then I installed the professional version instead of community and then it was gone. I've tried reinstalling and restarting several times. The MAUI templates just wont show up, even though the module is installed.

Any help to get out there? Thanks <3

EDIT:
I fixed it by using Gerald's dotnet install command.
However, to do that, I had to first delete everything from:
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
and then I could run his command, and now it works perfectly!

Comment: Even though it shouldn't be necessary, you should be able to install them manually by running `dotnet new install Microsoft.Maui.Templates` if the `install` keyword isn't working replace it with `--i`

Comment: Perfect! Added it as an answer for discoverability. Feel free to accept if you like. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Even though it shouldn't be necessary, you should be able to install them manually by running `dotnet new install Microsoft.Maui.Templates` if the install keyword isn't working replace it with `--i`

Comment: Thanks @Gerald Versluis. I was about to ask the same question but found the answer and it worked for me.