# MAUI Apps Broken with Visual Studio 2022 17.8

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022

After upgrading to VS 2022 17.8.1, none of my MAUI apps build and the MAUI template has gone.

Error message is
The result "" of evaluating the value "$(MicrosoftBuildTasksGitAssemblyFile)" of the "AssemblyFile" attribute in element  is not valid.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets

I have tried rollback to 17.7 but still no luck.

Comment: based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77493243/6609024 try and uninstall .net 8 too

Comment: This is an issue  on the GitHub. After upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 Preview to 17.8.0 Empty [MAUI App does not compile](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16652). You can rollback to the previous version before 17.6.

Comment: Does this help ? [.net MAUI templates not in Visual Studio 2022 community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921435/net-maui-templates-not-in-visual-studio-2022-community)